# AMFPHP Flex Propel Mapping class ultra-weird bug

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, propel, amfphp

I'm working on a website using :
- Flex 3.4
- AMFPHP 1.9b
- Propel 1.3
- PHP/MySQL

My problem is really strange and I've been spending hours trying to know where it comes from.

I'll try to focus on the problem which takes place in a whole system.

To sum up, I have 2 entities (MySQL) :

```
create table AAA
(
   id_AAA              int not null auto_increment,
   id_BBB              int,
   primary key (id_AAA)
)
type = innodb;

create table BBB
(
   id_BBB              int not null auto_increment,
)
type = innodb;

alter table AAA add constraint fk_AAA_BBB foreign key (id_BBB)
      references spot (id_BBB) on delete cascade on update cascade;
```

I retrieve all my BBB, they are mapped from PHP classes (generated by Propel) to AS3 classes on the Flex side.

But when I create a AAA row in the database.

I retrieve all my BBB, and all objects are mapped EXCEPT the BBB whose id corresponds to the foreign key in the inserted AAA row.

I really have no clue about why and how ... if you know anything about how AMFPHP / Propel / Flex are dealing with Foreign Keys and why class mapping is failing right here.

The weird thing is that it seems to happen only for this specific case ...

Thank you !

Comment: The problem is only coming from the Flex side.

The problem is still weird.
The object is instantiated somewhere else in the code, then class mapping fails for the object which is 100% similar !

This has nothing to do with static variables ?

This might be something deeper that I did not understand in Flex...

Comment: some example code might help.  Have you tried simplifying it down and reproducing it somewhere else?

Comment: Are both singletons using the same array? It's hard to say something without seeing the code.

Comment: I could try to simplify the problem to show you some code. I'll do this this week-end if I find some time.

Both singletons are using a different array coming from different amfphp remote-object calls.

Comment: Please see this :
First instantiation of the spot object
http://thommas.free.fr/FlexBug1.jpg

Second instantiation of the spot object failing
http://thommas.free.fr/FlexBug2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Class mapping is failing when making batch calls !

I read this to lead me to a solution :
http://amfphp.sourceforge.net/docs/commonerrors.html

When make AMFPHP remote object call one at the time, the objects are correctly mapped.